# Embedded Discovery service that does not require spring

Tags: java, jvm, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

Is there a simple JVM-based embedded discovery service like Eureka that does not require spring boot? All that I can find seem to be standalone apps, and I want something simple to keep track of all agent's addresses